# Firestore query not returning correct value for async await?

Tags: javascript, async-await, google-cloud-firestore

So below are a couple of short functions. createFeedPadFromScratch is my main function that is async and theoretically should wait for the getCurrentId function call to resolve before it consoles the currentId variable. The getCurrentId function is a simple firestore db query that returns a number. Inside of the getCurrentId function, the correct value is being consoled and I return that very value right after consoling it, but in the main function, when I console that return value, I get undefined?

```
async function createFeedPadFromScratch() {
    let currentId = await getCurrentId();
    console.log(currentId);
}

function getCurrentId() {
    let currentIdRef = db.collection('feedPads').doc('getId');
    var currentId;

    currentIdRef.get().then(function(doc) {
        if (doc.exists) {
            currentId = doc.data().currentId;
            console.log(currentId, typeof currentId);
            return new Promise(resolve => {
                resolve(currentId);
            });
        } else {
            // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
            console.log("No such document!");
        }
      }).catch(function(error) {
          console.log("Error getting document:", error);
    });
}
```

Comment: You need to return a promise from `getCurrentId` if you want to wait for it to complete. The function `getCurrentId` currently returns nothing at all (void).

Comment: See also [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/1260204)

Comment: @Igor Is that not what I am doing here? I thought my return statement above resolves the promise with currentId variable.

Comment: Where do you see a `return` statement in that method? (not in the promise callback, that is not the same thing)

Comment: @Igor Sorry, I'm just super confused right now, so you're saying the return new Promise statement is not a valid promise return statement?

Comment: **return** `currentIdRef.get().then(function(doc) { ...` **return** `currentId;....});`

Comment: 1. You have to return something from the method `getCurrentId` (first return in my above comment) *and* 2 you should return the value you want to resolve in your main method directly inside the promise call back, there is no need to wrap that in another promise.

Comment: @Igor, I tried returning inside of the callback and inside of the getCurrentId method itself to no avail. BUT, for some reason, it works when I do the following, set currentId variable = to the promise callback and then inside of the promise also return currentId query and then return currentId at the end of getCurrentId. Can you explain why it works this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm kind of confused why you aren't using async/await in both functions.  You can eliminate a lot of code by working with the syntax effectively and uniformly.

```
async function createFeedPadFromScratch() {
    try {
        let currentId = await getCurrentId();
        console.log(currentId);
    catch (error) {
       console.log("Error getting user id:", error);
    }
}

async function getCurrentId() {
    let currentIdRef = db.collection('feedPads').doc('getId');
    var currentId;

    const doc = await currentIdRef.get()
    if (doc.exists) {
        currentId = doc.data().currentId;
        console.log(currentId, typeof currentId);
        return currentId;
    } else {
        // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
        console.log("No such document!");
        return null;
    }
}
```